# Создание экземпляров класса в цикле Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

Привет, а как мне в цикле создавать экземпляры класса? не понимаю как менять имена переменных в каждой итерации цикла

Comment: Вы их хотите в массив сохранить?

Comment: нет, просто цикл инициализации объектов.

Comment: Тогда зачем вам цикл? Вы тогда так и так декларируете переменные в не цикла, верно? Тогда зачем Вам цикл. Так лучше сделайте массив, в цикле заполните его объектами.

Comment: массивом тоже в принципе можно, главное получить n одинаковых экземпляров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var objects = [ObjectType]()

for _ in 1...5 {
 let object = Object()
 objects.append(object)
}
```

Вот псевдокод, как в цикле заполнить массив, по той же логике сделайте со своими объектами.